# Custom interceptor to Inject bean into DistributedTask

Tags: java, infinispan

Is it possible to intercept a `DistributedTask` so I can manually inject some beans?

I'm expecting to write an interceptor that takes the task `Object`, find any field that has the `Inject` annotation and inject some beans that are s**pecific to the node that it is running on**.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible; you have to override the `visitDistributedExecuteCommand()` method in the interceptor. However it seems that the preferred approach is to implement `DistributedTaskLifecycle` and register it in `META-INF/services`, as CDI does.

Note that in Infinispan 9.0 the interceptor SPI will be changed (that's why all interceptors are deprecated in 8.2).

Comment: I've already given this a go, I can see my interceptor registers, but it doesn't run the `visitDistributedExecuteCommand()` method, but it runs the put/get visit methods.

Comment: Ah, I see it's not wrapped in SingleRpcCommand and therefore it gets invoked directly. So, it being and VisitableCommand (and the method in the interceptors) is confusing, can you file a JIRA?

Comment: I certainly can raise a JIRA. With regards to your second suggestion, without really knowing much about CDI, is it possible to do this programatically at runtime? Essentially I want to pull things out of my Guice container and inject them prior to running the task

Comment: It seems you can't do that during runtime :-/ But you can install a generic DistributedTaskLifecycle that will multiplex the call to runtime-registered implementations.

Comment: I am not a fan of ServiceLoaders, but it was obviously implemented with the intention of calling the lifecycle callback in extension module, not really a user-registered one.